EMI Filter Selection for SN65HVD1050D: Inductance or Impedance Priority?
In my project, I am using the SN65HVD1050D CAN transceiver and need to add an EMI filter (common mode choke) for the CAN_L and CAN_H lines.
Typically, I see EMI filters with an inductance value of 51 µH widely used in the market. However, the components I want to use specify their impedance instead of inductance, and the impedance is 90 Ω @ 100 MHz. The components I am considering are Murata DLW21SZ900HQ2L, TDK ACM2012-900-2P-T002.
My Questions:
For a CANbus EMI filter, which is more critical: inductance (µH) or impedance (Ω)?
Can filters with 90 Ω @ 100 MHz impedance perform as effectively as those with 51 µH inductance?
Will these components provide sufficient EMI suppression and maintain signal integrity on my CANbus line?
Application Notes:
My CANbus operates at 1 Mbps.
There aren't many noise sources in my circuit, but I want to ensure signal integrity.

"need to add an EMI filter" -- what evidence do you have to support this claim? It appears to come out of nowhere, but this is not why we use EMI filters.

CAN bus is quite slow.
A CM choke with 51uH inductance may have  3000 to 4000 ohms impedance at 40 to 50 MHz range. They are meant to be filters that allow the slow CAN communications to pass well, and can block noise above it.
These are quite big and heavy components.
The ones you say have 90 ohms  CM impedance at 100 MHz are quite different. They are intended for 100 ohm high speed differential communication, happening at multiple Gbps or even 10 Gbps, such as USB, HDMI, DisplayPort, Ethernet or the like. They just block the EMI that might be present on the wires. And CAN is much slower.
So while they both do block EMI, they block EMI at different range that is due to different reasons.
